# no-unsafe-optional-chaining does not work with "||" or condition

Tags: javascript, error-handling, eslint, lint

[no-unsafe-optional-chaining](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unsafe-optional-chaining) is an amazing eslint rule, which help us identify why we are doing wrong with **optional chaining**..

I have one case where i need to perform a `sort` operation on id (in `numbers`) which could be in `string` type which make sense to **throw error** because the it could result in `NaN` if `order` is not a number

```js
  const sortComparer = (a, b) => (+a?.order) - (+b?.order)
```

However, if i do handle `no-unsafe-optional-chaining` as follow it still throws error and does not work:

```js
  const sortComparer = (a, b) => (+a.order || 0) - (+b.order || 0),
```

The only way to make it work is like this:

```js
  const sortComparer = (a, b) => (a?.order ? +a.order : 0) - (b?.order ? +b.order : 0),
```

Does anyone know how to fix this in a better way to avoid this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
sortComparer: (a, b) => +(a?.order || 0) - +(b?.order || 0),
```

Move the `+` out of the `()`, and use the optional chaining to handle `a` or `b`  being `null`.